# JS/JQuery change class and SlideDown/Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page with a top menu that changes into a minimized version when the user scrolls down. I'm doing this by changing the class of the element, so the CSS changes its appearance.

I would like to perform a simple slideDown/slideUp, as the minimized menu bar appears/disappears, at the same time, but just adding the animation to my current code doesn't work as I hoped it would.

Here's the code snippet I'm using to minimize the menu:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() < topMenuHeight) {
        $("nav").removeClass("min");      
    } else {
        $("nav").addClass("min");
    } 
});
```

topMenuHeight refers to the menu's height (obviously) and was set as a variable previously on the code.

How can I make this work? I had tried setting a variable to check if the menu was minimized or not, but it didn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated. Although, I know there are some animation plugins out there, but for this project I want to keep it lean.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is an example with slideUp and slideDown

CSS

```
nav {
    height: 200px;
    background: lightblue;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: -16px;
}
nav.min {
    position: fixed;
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(this).scrollTop() != 0  && !$("nav").hasClass("min"))
    {
       $("nav").slideUp(function(){
           $("nav").addClass("min");
           $("nav").slideDown();
       });
    }
    else if($(this).scrollTop() == 0 && $("nav").hasClass("min"))
    {
        $("nav").slideUp(function(){
            $("nav").removeClass("min");
            $("nav").slideDown();
        });    
     }
});
```

FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/VD6wf/22/

Comment: That's what I had tried, but when I first scroll down, instead of changing the class, it slides up the expanded menu (so it disappears); then, as I keep scrolling, it slides up the minimized version or maybe I need to trigger the class change differently. I imagine it's because it's all the same element. I would rather not add any extraneous markup. Do you have any other ideas? Thank you!

Comment: The code has some complexity, I will try to slim it down and post it there. But I found a workaround. I set the "min" class to have a negative top value, then on the JS scroll trigger, I'm animating the top property to 0. It works, but not quite 100% as it should, sometimes the bar appears and then disappears again... I think the way I'm triggering the scrolling is causing some trouble.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/VD6wf/19/ It kind of works, but as you scroll up and down, it's very buggy. Thanks for looking!

Comment: @worksAsIntended Okay i'll take a look at it tomorrow morning and get back to you.

Comment: I played around with it a little bit more (see below) and it seems to be OK. But if you have the opportunity to look into it, maybe suggest a more efficient way to do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: @worksAsIntended Well I made an example for you.  Not sure if its what your going for.  But demonstrates how to use slideUp and slideDown.

Comment: That looks great, thank you very much! I would give you an upvote but I'm a new user and Stackoverflow won't let me. :)

Answer (score 0):

This (adding a stop) seems to have solved the glitch:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() < topMenuHeight+100) {
    $("nav").stop().animate({ 
     top: "-4em"
     }, 200, function() {
      $("nav").removeClass("min"); 
     });      
  } else {
    $("nav").addClass("min");
    $("nav").stop().animate({ 
     top: 0
    }, 200 );
  } 
 });
});
```